# Is it true that to be a faithful Muslim woman, I cannot hold a job?

Tags: fiqh, human-rights

Assalamualaikum,

For years, I have been taught that, according to Islam, it is better for Muslim girls to stay at home. Girls should not go outside without the permission of their parents or husband. Getting jobs and working with unrelated males is also strictly prohibited.

**Is it true that to be a faithful Muslim woman, I cannot hold a job or build up an identity of my own?**

Comment: Mahira, I slightly reformatted your question for better readability. If you disagree with my changes, please feel free to click on edit and roll-back my changes.

Comment: Just by my humble opinion, all I can say is that you can definitely hold a job as a female while being a faithful Muslim. All you have to do is this...."BE MODEST". Honestly, I am quite curious as to where you have learnt that better Muslims girls have to stay at home or girls can't go outside. I personally want your opinion on the matter with proper islamic references to back your statements.

Comment: Let me answer in questions, as I am not truly sure: Who was the first wife of Prophet Muhammad? What was her profession?

Answer (score 0):

In general it is not haram. However certain jobs are haram. One’s husband or father-if not married-should also allow it. The idea of being an independent women is not as pleasing as one thinks, and could outright be dangerous in certain cities.

Answer (score -2):

In the Qur'an or the sunnah, it does not say anywhere that working as a woman is haram. Islam treats both genders equally, however, each has different jobs. Is it not true that men have to avoid women, or at least lower their gaze? That does not mean it is prohibited for them to work. I understand where your concern is, but the consensus seems to be that the quranic verse (33:33) that says:

> “And stay in your houses, and do not display yourselves like that of the times of ignorance”

means you should not go out except for that which is necessary. Work is not displaying yourself for the sake of it, no. It is to earn money, to earn a living. If Allah granted us the chance to work jobs to help our ummah, it is not haram unless the haram itself is integrated into the said job. If the job encourages haram work, then it is deemed haram. If it doesn't, I do not see a problem

Comment: Yes, BUT a job is only prohibited if you do have a mahram male that earns money like Husband, father, etc. If you simply want to build an identity of your own like mentioned in the question, It is not prohibited for women to do so.